# drivers nvidia, ubuntu don't see second mo

Tags: driver, nvidia

[I have problem with drivers on my PC. For the first Nvidia X settings are empty(like we can see on screen. I installed drivers with instuctions in https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04, but this method doesnt work. I tried on software&updating in additional drivers and nothing change(All time i have: DRIVERS: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) like second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl29y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Njuf.png)

Summary, Ubuntu don't see my second screen after some update. I'm sure my devices are ok because on windows 10 all it's alright.
Maybe somebody have some hints for it?

Comment: I think it is better to search/ask at https://askubuntu.com

Comment: ok, i'll do that. Thx